# SqlAlchemy logging "SystemError: error return without exception set"

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, cpython

I'm currently developing a web-app which uses a combination of SqlAlchemy Flask and Marshmallow to serialize SQLite data into JSON for the front-end. I've used this setup on multiple occasions which worked fine, however, this time my console is continuously spammed with the following errors:

```
    Exception ignored in: <generator object surface_selectables at 0x13b399888>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/luke/Documents/Projects/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 231, in surface_selectables
    yield elem
SystemError: error return without exception set
Exception ignored in: <generator object _visitor_iterator at 0x13b399888>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/luke/Documents/Projects/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 150, in _visitor_iterator
    yield v
SystemError: error return without exception set
Exception ignored in: <generator object _visitor_iterator at 0x13b399888>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/luke/Documents/Projects/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 150, in _visitor_iterator
    yield v
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

This causes my application to slow down due to the fact that it needs to process so much text in the window, and requests can sometimes take up to five seconds to complete. After looking online I've found out this might be caused by some library written in CPython that returns an incorrect exception object: <sup>[source](http://pythonextensionpatterns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exceptions.html#exception-raising)</sup>

> If one of the two actions is missing then the exception will not be
>   raised correctly. For example returning NULL without setting an
>   exception type:
>
> ```
> /* Illustrate returning NULL but not setting an exception. */
> static PyObject *_raise_error_bad(PyObject *module) {
>     return NULL;
> }
> ```
>
> Executing this from Python will produce a clear error message (the C
>   function _raise_error_bad() is mapped to the Python function
>   cExcep.raiseErrBad()
>
> ```
> >>> cExcep.raiseErrBad()
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> SystemError: error return without exception set
> ```

Example code which triggers the error (completely valid and works most of the time):

```
MyTable.query.filter_by(guid=room["guid"]).first()
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Looking at the stack traces it's something to do with SqlAlchemy and Generators but I can't seem to figure out why it's doing this. Thanks

- Python version: 3.6.3
- Flask version: 0.12.2
- Flask SqlAlchemy version: 2.3.2

---

Edit: The following is the result of `pip freeze` from my virtualenv when I last worked on the project (which resulted in the errors appearing):

```
alembic==0.9.8
APScheduler==3.5.3
asn1crypto==0.24.0
bleach==2.1.3
certifi==2018.4.16
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
check-manifest==0.37
click==6.7
cmarkgfm==0.4.2
colorama==0.3.9
coverage==4.5.1
cryptography==2.3.1
docutils==0.14
Flask==0.12.2
flask-marshmallow==0.8.0
Flask-Migrate==2.1.1
Flask-SocketIO==2.9.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Flask-Testing==0.7.1
future==0.16.0
gevent-websocket==0.10.1
gitflow.releaser==2.0.4
greenlet==0.4.13
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
Mako==1.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.0
marshmallow==2.14.0
marshmallow-enum==1.4.1
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.13.2
mysql-connector-python==8.0.6
pkginfo==1.4.2
pycparser==2.18
Pygments==2.2.0
PyMySQL==0.9.2
pyroma==2.3.1
python-dateutil==2.7.0
python-editor==1.0.3
python-engineio==2.0.3
python-socketio==1.9.0
pytz==2018.5
readme-renderer==20.0
requests==2.18.4
requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
six==1.11.0
SQLAlchemy==1.2.5
stringcase==1.2.0
tqdm==4.23.4
twine==1.11.0
tzlocal==1.5.1
urllib3==1.22
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.14.1
zest.releaser==6.15.0
```

Comment: Hi @paradoxis, this is very bizzare I'm having the exact same error under nearly the exact same circumstances, have you raised an issue with sqlalchemy/python/flask?

Comment: @Ruthus99 not yet, but if you do let me know I'd love to know the response from them. It's mainly a very annoying issue rather than a breaking one so my priority isn't on it as much. I've actually had the same sort of error occur in my own applications (heavily multithreaded) when an error occurred in a thread. Might have something to do with it if SqlAlchemy uses threading underneath the hood

Comment: not sure if useful, but I've found that this only happens on my Development server (Mac OS) and not on my production (Ubuntu with Apache and modWSGI). Furthermore, the error has got so bad that it means I cannot use my development server without having 'developer tools' open in the browser, I think it's got something to do with the fact that having this open clears the cache upon every request.

Comment: @Ruthus99 I'm also working on a Mac, might be related to that somehow

Comment: This is almost certainly the *database driver*. What database connection library are you using?

Comment: sqlalchemy with engine `mysql+pymysql`

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was using the default `sqlite://` driver, but I also had the same issue using MySQL. I believe it's related to MacOS more than anything, as I haven't had the issue under Linux or Windows. I haven't found a solution since I posted it and it's marked as a simple annoyance as it doesn't affect our production environment

Comment: @Paradoxis: hrm, that complicates matters. It's not the generators, those are just the point that control from a C extension is back in Python's hands and the discrepancy is noticed. Some C extension is mucking up here. But the fact that you get this error with a *pure Python database driver* means that whatever is mucking this up is perhaps something that runs in another thread or is injecting hooks into Python's interpreter loop, making it harder to locate. You'd have to bisect your whole application, disabling functionality and imports.

Comment: @Paradoxis: If you are using gevents, or uvloop, or this is part of a WSGI server stack that uses those, etc, then those would be suspect. But this is not a one-size-fits-all remedy to your situation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I do have gevent installed, I just updated my question to include my project's `pip freeze` output, hope it helps

Comment: This is not something I or anyone else here is likely to be able to help with. The Python generator machinery relies on exceptions to signal certain events, and that's the moment that Python notices the discrepancy. It's something else that happened just before that caused the bad state, but *we can't see what that is*, and a list of packages is not likely to reveal that either. You could go through each project's issue tracker and see if there are potentially relevant issues, and update to latest versions, but that's about it.

Comment: Also I suffer from it on Mac and it seems not having side effect